# Activate azure function only after another function have executed?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, serverless

I have a `PostStartupSetup` azure functions that will run on every startup

```cs
[FunctionName(nameof(PostStartupSetup))]
public async Task PostStartupSetup([TimerTrigger("0 0 0 29 2 6", RunOnStartup = true)]TimerInfo t)
{
    // do startup tasks
}
```

I then have some functions with `ServiceBusTrigger`'s that relies on my `PostStartupSetup` to have completed. Is it possible to somehow only activate those functions AFTER my `PostStartupSetup` function have finished executed?

Comment: Do you mean that your other functions with ServiceBusTrigger should start listening to the service bus messages after PostStartupSetup completes. Your PostStartupSetup function above is timer triggered which would run at 12:00 AM, on day 29 of the month, only on Saturday, only in February. Did you make that to avoid running periodically? Well last time it happened was in 2020 by the way :)

Comment: Yeah exactly. I simply just want to make sure my ServiceBusTrigger  functions only run if PostStartupSetup have executed at least once since startup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No straight forward way but here are few options:

1. If you're dedicated plan you can use [Durable Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-overview?tabs=csharp), set some shared variable to true/false to indicate if "startup" is complete or not and if it's not complete then all other functions would keep failing with appropriate Error code.
2. If you're on consumption plan then you could use some cheap options like storage tables to share state across functions and do the same.
3. You could truly disable (not tested) functions and enable them dynamically:

   - [Disable all your functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/disable-function) at deployment.
   - Inside `PostStartupSetup()` [enable all functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/webapps/updateapplicationsettings) by updating the app settings to enable all functions.